# What is the difference between vector space and vector span?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Their definitions sound the same to me - each being a set of all vectors such that each vector can be represented as a linear combination of other vectors in the set.

Comment: 'vector span' is really not  a valid terminology. You can talk about the vector space spanned by a set of vectors but not 'vector span'.

Answer (score 3):

A vector space is a set of elements (called "vectors"), along with some form of vector addition and scalar multiplication, subject to a list of requirements for how these two operations behave. Something is only a vector if it is part of a vector space.

With that out of the way, given some set $X$ of vectors (all from the same vector space $V$), you can ask about their span. That is defined as the set of all elements of $V$ that can be reached using only the vectors in $X$ and the vector space operations of $V$ (including arbitrary scaling). The span of a set of vectors turns out to also be a vector space (a *subspace* of $V$), but you need a vector space first before you can talk about a span.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! If, for example, the vector we have in R2 is given by x=[1 -1], I believe the span would be the diagonal line that runs 45 degree angle from the origin into quadrants II and IV, where the vector [1 -1] lies, right? And, I guess the vector space would be the collection of all vectors {cx | c is an element of R}?

Comment: @SamyamShrestha Sounds good to me. Note that you have to establish $\Bbb R^2$ as a vector space first (and not just a collection of points), before anything in the rest of your comment. You haven't said so, because $\Bbb R^2$ is so standard one usually doesn't. But it's usually a good idea to be somewhat conscious of the fact anyways.

Comment: just a bad analogy if I understand this perfectly: Let's say [50] is a vector space, which is a closed set. If so, the span of [50] includes all x's and y's such that ∃c,d such that cx+dy=50. Is this a good way of understanding it?

Comment: @SamyamShrestha [50] is not a conventional vector space in any way that I know of. The real number line is a common vector space, as is the plane. If you mean the _vector_ $[50]$ as an element of the vector space $\Bbb R$, then the span of that vector is all of $\Bbb R$ (assuming the scalar multiplication uses the real numbers).

Comment: yeah, [50] is not a vector space. I was just trying to give an example in a layman's terms involving simple algebraic terms, non-vectors. If 50 as a number is a space, and x and y are the span of 50 such as cx+dy=50. I was wondering if you interchange these with real vectors, if it would be equivalent of what vector space and span are?

Comment: @SamyamShrestha As an example, take $\Bbb R^3$, the 3-dimensional (real) vector space. Here vectors look like $(1, -42, \pi)$. Take the two vectors $(1, 0, 0)$ and $(0,1,0)$. Their span contains _all_ vectors of the form $$a(1,0,0) + b(0,1,0)$$ for real numbers $a, b$. Which is to say, a vector is part of the span iff its third component is $0$. This span is commonly called the $xy$ plane.

Comment: this makes total sense. So a vector space is normally in the form of R2 or R3 or R4, right?

Comment: @SamyamShrestha Yes, that's mostly what you will encounter. At least initially. Some times they might hide it (the set of polynomials of degree $2$ or less, with standard addition and scaling, might look different, but is really just a camouflaged $\Bbb R^3$). And eventually you will encounter both infinite dimensional spaces and spaces over other scaling fields (e.g. $\Bbb C$).

Answer (score 3):

This is an old thread but I'll post anyway.

The vector span of a set of vectors defined in the same vector space is either the same vector space or a sub-space of it.

Let's take as an example a 3D vector space. For simplicity let's assume it's real-valued, i.e. it's R<sup>3</sup>.

**1.Case: the span may be just a point**

If you have 2 all-zero vectors (i.e. they are identical to the origin) then they span only a single point (the origin). Now matter how you combine them linearly they cannot "protrude" beyond the origin. Thus their span is a point (which is a subspace of the original space R<sup>3</sup>)

**2.Case: the span may be a line**

Another case is if the set contains, essentially, just scaled versions of the same vector. Let's say you have these three vectors: [1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3]. They are on the same line. Now matter how you combine them linearly you cannot "leave" that line - the result of their linear combination is on the same line (their span is that line - which is itself a subspace of the original space R<sup>3</sup>)

**3.Case: the span may be a plane**

Another case is if all three vectors are on the same plane, e.g. they are of the form:

[x1, y1, 0], [x2, y2, 0], [x3, y3, 0].

As you may notice, the third component for each of them is 0. They are all on the same plane

Now matter how you combine them linearly the result will have as a 3rd component 0 - it will be still on the same plane. This plane is their span. And that plane is subspace of the original space R3.

**4.Case: the vector span is the same as the original vector space**

This is the trivial example where three 3D vectors span the entire 3D space.

**Generalisation**

How big is the span in relation to the original space is related to whether the vectors are **linearly independent**. If they are not (as is in the first 3 cases) their span is, plainly speaking, a fraction of the original space.

A "set of linearly independent vectors" means that no vector in the set can be produced as a linear combination of the others. In the first 3 cases we were dealing with **linearly dependent** vectors.

Comment: I'm glad you want to help, but please don't post on old threads when you have nothing new important to add. It moves the question to the active queue and attracts attention from folks like me who follow that queue. Look at new unanswered questions. Do use mathjax formatting  here.